# Restrict users to access mail merge template

Tags: mail-merge

How can I restrict users to access mail merge templates? When users are taken to the mail merge page, I only want to give access to particular templates for that particular user.

Comment: take all template in one folder and give user access of that folder only.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new folder in your Email templates.

1. Decide to give Read Only/Read Write Permission.
2. Select the templates you want to make them available in this folder.
3. At the bottom, select **"This folder is accessible only by the following users"** and then choose the Users you want to give the access to.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not asking about Email Templates. These are Mail Merge templates which are accessed by Setup-->Communication Templates-->Mail Merge Templates. There is no scope of creating any folder and providing permissions to users based on folder here. So if I want any user to have access to only one template and not all, what do I need to do?